# Agda as a programming language

Tags: documentation, agda

I have found a lot of useful information on using Agda as a proof system. I have found virtually no information on using Agda to write usable programs. I cannot even find a "hello world" example that compiles with the most recent version of Agda.

So,

1. Are there any good tutorials on Agda as a programming language?
2. Are there other languages of a similar nature (lazy functional dependently typed) that have more mature documentation for using them as a programming language? (I found tons of great documentation on Coq, but, again, no "Hello World").

Comment: How hard did you look? I found [Tutorials](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Othertutorials) in less than a minute. The first pdf has a hello world at the end (section 4.3).

Comment: Which, alas, does not compile with current Agda :(

Comment: I can point you to [Idris](http://idris-lang.org/); functional, dependently typed, eager with explicit laziness anotation. It is also very Haskell (and Agda) like.

Comment: this may be of interest for you: [lemmachine](https://github.com/larrytheliquid/Lemmachine) -- REST'ful web framework written in agda

Comment: @maxtaldykin That is indeed a great example! You should post it as an answer.

Comment: I agree that there is no clear and easy way to get to know this language, no step by step way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To print a string in Agda, you need the [std lib](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Libraries.StandardLibrary). You can find a "hello world" example [here](http://progopedia.com/example/hello-world/251/) for Agda 2.2.6 and std lib 0.3. This example doesn't work for current Agda 2.3.0 and std lib 0.6. I read some sources in std lib 0.6, and find that the following one works:

```
module hello where

open import IO.Primitive using (IO; putStrLn)
open import Data.String using (toCostring; String)
open import Foreign.Haskell using (Unit)

main : IO Unit
main = putStrLn (toCostring "Hello, Agda!")
```

To compile it, you need

1. save it to "./hello.agda"
2. download lib-0.6.tar.gz, and unpack it to somewhere, say DIR
3. cd DIR/ffi && cabal install
4. agda -i DIR/src -i . -c hello.agda

On my MacOSX Lion with ghc-7.4.2 and cabal-1.16.0, this example works fine. I get an executable program named "hello" with size 19.1M.

Comment: Hello world @ 20M is pretty ridiculous

Comment: Why do you need to do cabal install? 
Also, it asks for permission.
Also, when I give it my admin password, it still says permission denied.

Comment: Is there a way to use the FFI modules without installing them?

Comment: I am a bit afraid of languages that encourage abbreviation: `putStrLn`. Readability should be a concern of language design, not just theoretical correctness.

Answer (score 7):

This is nascent, but one-day might become a useful resource:

https://github.com/liamoc/learn-you-an-agda

Comment: Three years later, unfortunately still nascent.

Comment: Not nascent anymore: seems it has died ...